# Как все объекты класса запустить в Map?

Tags: java, словарь

Хочу, чтобы все объекты класса, которые будут созданы пользователем, заносились в Map,чтобы в будущем к ним можно было обращаться через их ключи

Comment: И что же вам мешает?

Comment: то, что создание объекта, создание и занесение в мап находятся в разных классах и у меня не получается к ним нормально обратиться

Comment: Значит у вас архитектурные проблемы. Покажите код, хотя бы схематично

Comment: Сделайте класс-фабрику, добавьте ей создание ваших объектов класса, а классу-фабрике добавьте статичное поле с словарем, куда и будете добавлять объекты